# Android: Null safe equals before API v19

Tags: android, api, null, equals

I have two objects `Object1` and `Object2`, which may or may not be null.
I want to test null safe equality between them (true if both null, or both equal)
I have done my research and found `Objects.equals(Object1,Object2)`, which fulfills its purpose.

But the problem is that it's only for API level 19+. 
How do I make this compatible with lesser APIs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several options.

1. You could override the 
   `equals()` method in the class you are comparing,  and use `obj1.equals(obj2)`
2. You could use the `hashCode()` method of Object to determine if they are equivalent,  by using `obj1.hashCode() == obj2.hashCode()`
3. Just using plain old `==` determines weather two variables contain the same instance of a class.

If these aren't null safe,  you can easily write your own null checking with `obj == null`

This should be completely independent of the Android Api.

Comment: +1 for write your own method.  There is no magic behind what `Objects.equals(...)` does.  Android is open source, so depending on the license of your own code, you might be able to just copy the method into your own utility class.

Comment: Do not use hashCode() method to determine equality. Its very very bad.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Guava?
Guava has some pretty nice functionality that removes alot of the boilerplate.
Here is a [link](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CommonObjectUtilitiesExplained) of their example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple comparison method.  It seems odd that you have to roll your own, though.

```
/**
 * Null safe comparison of two objects.
 * @return true if the objects are identical.
 */
public static boolean objectEquals(Object o1, Object o2) {
    if (o1 == null && o2 == null) return true;
    if (o1 == null) return false;
    return o1.equals(o2);
}
```